# Как сделать двойную сортировку в HashSet или чем его заменить?

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть задача:

> Реализуйте `countWords()` метод в классе `Words`. Входной параметр -
> это список строк, представляющих строки текста. Подсчет слов -
> сопоставление слов в нижнем регистре с их частотой в тексте.  Если
> слово «котик» встречается в тексте 23 раза, то его записью будет
> «котик - 23 \ n» .  Пропускать любое слово длиной менее 4 и частотой
> менее 10 (например, слишком маленькие или слишком редкие слова).
> Возвращает строку, содержащую все записи.  Записи в результирующей
> строке также следует отсортировать по количеству, а затем, если
> необходимо, в алфавитном порядке. Вы не можете использовать потоки или
> лямбды в своем коде.

Вот что пока получилось:

```
public class Words {

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> newWords = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> againWords = new ArrayList<>();
    Hashtable<String, Integer> heshWord = new Hashtable<>();
    //String endString;
    String up;


    public String countWords(List<String> lines) {
        words.addAll(lines);//Приняли все строки, сложили в words


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);//Паттерн что бы отсеять при переборе

        ListIterator iterator = words.listIterator();//Итератор по words
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String stringLine = (String) iterator.next();
            String str = stringLine.replaceAll(pattern.pattern(), " ").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);//отсеять все по патерну
            String[] strMassive = str.split(" ");
            for (String s : strMassive) {
                if (s.length() > 3) {//Убрать слова меньше 4 букв
                    newWords.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        
        Set<String> setString = new HashSet<String>(newWords);
        for (String s : setString) {
            System.out.println(s + " - " + Collections.frequency(newWords, s));



            int num = Collections.frequency(newWords, s);
            //1. Отсортировать по кол-ву повторений, потом, если есть повторы, то по алфавиту
            //2. Перенести в String и вернуть.

            up= newWords.toString();
        }
        return up;
    }
}
```

Проблемы:

1. Не получается сделать сортировку в `HashSet` по количеству совпадений (а потом еще и по алфавиту, если несколько с одинаковым кол-вом совпадений), что лучше вместо него использовать и как? Напрашивается `HashMap`, но и с ним пока не работает.
2. Как перенести получившийся лист в `String`? Как не пытаюсь либо выходит ссылка на строку, либо строка которую нельзя редактировать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении смотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если стримы под запретом, то придется делать что-то в этом духе:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordsCounter {

    private final int minWordLength, minCount;

    public WordsCounter(int minWordLength, int minCount) {
        this.minWordLength = minWordLength;
        this.minCount = minCount;
    }

    public List<WordCount> countWords(String text, String regexDelimeter) {
        return sortWithLimit(getWordsCount(text.split(regexDelimeter)));
    }

    private Map<String, WordCount> getWordsCount(String[] text) {
        Map<String, WordCount> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : text) {
            if (word.length() < minWordLength) continue;
            String lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCase();
            map.put(lowerCaseWord, map.containsKey(lowerCaseWord)
                    ? map.get(lowerCaseWord).addCount() : new WordCount(word));
        }
        return map;
    }
    
    private List<WordCount> sortWithLimit(Map<String, WordCount> map){
        List<WordCount> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getCount() > minCount) {
                return list.subList(i, list.size());
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(0);
    }
    
}

class WordCount implements Comparable<WordCount> {

    private final String value;
    private Integer count;

    public WordCount(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.count = 1;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public WordCount addCount() {
        count++;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordCount o) {
        int compareCount = count.compareTo(o.getCount());
        return compareCount == 0 ? value.compareTo(o.getValue()) : compareCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + " - " + count;
    }

}
```

Конструктор класса принимает минимальную длину слова и минимальную частоту (по вашему условию это 4 и 10). дальше все просто...

Comment: Большое спасибо) Я думаю это очень мне поможет!)